# How to start browser as different user with SeleniumLibrary keywords?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am using SeleniumLibrary which is a wrapper for Selenium to use with Robot Framework.

In some cases I need to start the browser as a different user because the application I am testing will otherwise use my Windows credentials (SSO) which I do not want.

This is easy to do manually with the Windows "run as" feature. I can also automate this in various ways.

However: I need to automate this "run as" using SeleniumLibrary, because if the browser isn't started using Selenium, I can't automate my actions in it using Selenium either.

I have looked into desired capabilities of the webdriver but there don't seem to be any posibilities there. I have found solutions here that say I should use a browser profile, but without explanation on how to setup such a profile using a different user.
I also found [this solution](https://www.gerbenvanadrichem.com/quality-assurance/how-to-get-selenium-to-run-the-browser-as-a-different-user/) but I don't really understand it, it uses Selenium directly which I cannot do and it seems to require the code to run on a different machine with the required user logged in there which isn't a possibility for me.

I need to be able to run a browser on the same machine without it using the credentials of the logged in Windows user.

TL/DR version:
How can I start a browser session using "open browser" or "create webdriver" keywords in SeleniumLibrary?

The solution needs to work with the common browsers IE, Chrome and Firefox (and possibly Edge)

Comment: I would like to start a browser as a different user because the application I want to test uses single sign-on and would otherwise use the credentials of my logged in Windows user.
But that Windows user doesn't have sufficient rights for the application so I need to be able to login with a user who does have the correct rights.

Comment: Do you have this issue when working in an Incognito browser?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [comments from Jim Evans](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/4354#issuecomment-318030059) (Creator IE Driver) on a [similar GitHub Issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/4354) this is a wish that won't be supported.

> ... we won't be adding a Windows-only feature to a cross-platform API
>   ...

In addition the [referenced article](https://www.gerbenvanadrichem.com/quality-assurance/how-to-get-selenium-to-run-the-browser-as-a-different-user/) highlights that the regular programming route to take doesn't work as expected.

This is why the article's writer fell back on having multiple machines with a different user logged into each. This circumvents the problem, not solves it. Given that you desire a single machine setup, I'm going to say that this isn't possible with the current software support; whatever the browser brand.

Comment: Yes I have read that too. But is starting a browser as a different user a Windows only thing? I can image the method to do this (shift-right click, run as) is Windows only but the idea in principle should apply to any operating system?

Anyways I am not surprised if this is indeed not possible with the current implementation of Selenium.

Thank you for your answer.